# How to add dynamic options using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gsp page and on that have a '`<g:select>`' element as:

```
<label class="control-label">Applicable Offices:</label>
<span class="span6">
    <select name="data.OfficeId" class="required j-office-select" style="height:26px;padding:1px;">
        <option value="0">Select an office...</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

I have to **add more "option" dynamically** for this select using JavaScript. My JavaScript part looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: epcm.urlManager.getUrl({controller: 'controllerName', action:'methodName'}),
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    success: function(officeData) {
        var selectOffice = dialog.find('.j-office-select');
        selectOffice.empty();
        // OfficeData is a list . For each officeData , I need to add an option to the’ select’, but ways I tried did not work.I need to know the proper use of $.each and how can I use that in this context
        selectOffice.append('<option value="'+officeData.id+'">'+officeData.regionName+'</option>' );
        selectOffice.removeAttr('disabled');
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

"OfficeData", in the "success", is a list. For **each officeData**, I need to add an option to the ’select’ described above, but the ways I tried did not work. I need help with the proper use of `$.each` and how can I use that in this context. Can anyone help? The above example is adding only the first one, missing all others.

Comment: Is the element disabled when you try to do this? I see "selectOffice.removeAttr('disabled');" in your code.

Comment: `window.location.reload();` this will reload the page and you will lose your added options....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
$.each(officeData, function(index, item){
   selectOffice.append('<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.regionName+'</option>' );
} );
```

However, in your example it does not seem like officeData is a collection since officeData.id and officeData.regionName are not nested inside items. You could use `console.log(officeData);` to output the data structure to your browser console (assuming you are using something like Chrome or FireFox+devtools).

Comment: Thank you Simon.Only comment ( for my benefit , may be for others too ): I found that  officeData has a collection named 'data' and 'data' has actual information. In that case just make a change to look like:  $.each(officeData.data, function(index, item){